# PHP not reading RSS file when live, but reads fine when local

Tags: php, rss

My local server reads the RSS fine, but when I upload it I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: fopen(http://webservice.weatherzone.com.au/rss/wx.php?u=13145&lt=aploc&lc=6439&fc=1) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /var/www/vhosts/---------------------- on line 105
Error reading RSS data.
```

I cannot post the URL to the site because I'm still working on it and its a security issue. And I'm not able to modify the php.ini file...

This is the code where it is called:

```
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();    
$rss_parser = new RSSParser();    
xml_set_object($xml_parser,&$rss_parser);    
xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "startElement", "endElement");    
xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "characterData");    
**$fp = fopen("http://webservice.weatherzone.com.au/rss/wx.php?u=13145&lt=aploc&lc=6439&fc=1","r")    
   or die("Error reading RSS data.");**    
while ($data = fread($fp, 4096))    
   xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fp))    
       or die(sprintf("XML error: %s at line %d",    
           xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($xml_parser)),    
           xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser)));    
fclose($fp);    
xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
```

Comment: I don't know if its an issue, but if you want to keep everything kinda secret, you might want to remove the file-location in the warning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use fopen() to read files from Web.

Try cURL instead, if installed:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch); // xml-code in $content
curl_close($ch);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: resulted in:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Comment: phpinfo:
curl
CURL support  enabled  
CURL Information  libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8c zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5

Comment: does `$content = file_get_contents($url)` work? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(http://webservice.weatherzone.com.au/rss/wx.php?u=13145&lt=aploc&lc=6439&fc=1) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Comment: What does `var_dump($http_response_header);` print after calling `file_get_contents($url)`? Is the HTTP statuscode `200`?

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(http://webservice.weatherzone.com.au/rss/wx.php?u=13145&lt=aploc&lc=6439&fc=1) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /var/www/vhosts/------------ on line 105
array(0) { }

Comment: Okay, I've no idea. Maybe there is a firewall blocking the request.. I think you should contact your webhoster.

Comment: The site I was having this problem on was for demo for a client off our company site, I just got the hosting info to move it over and file_get_contents($url) worked on the server it will be on :) 
Still weird that it wouldn't work on our server though.

Answer (score 2):

Probably `allow_url_fopen` is disabled. Please check using `ini_get()` or `phpinfo()`.

Comment: according to phpinfo:
allow_url_fopen On On

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would think of - do you have `allow_url_fopen` enabled in your PHP.ini file?  If not, you would need to enable that to use a URL with the fopen() function.

Even if it is set correctly, you might want to use the `curl` functions instead to make it less dependent on ini settings.